# coloring a $n\times n$ square grid in a specific way

Tags: combinatorics

I recently saw a maths problem that looked fun to solve. I have a $n\times n$ square grid and I need to color the cells within the grid in such a manner that no $2\times 2$ square that is within the larger grid has 3 of its 4 cells colored(it can be 1 or 2 or sometimes 0) and when all the necessary cells are colored if you color any of the empty cells there must be a 2*2 square (within the larger grid) which has $3$ cells colored.

It is a hard problem to wrap your mind around.

Everything up untill the $5\times 5$ grid is not hard to solve. For example, there is only one solution for a $2\times2$ grid.

No $2\times2$ square within the $3\times3$ square grid has 3 cells colored and if you were to color any of the empty cells there would be at least one $2\times2$ square which has 3 cells colored.

I also have solutions for the $5\times 5$ and $6\times6$ grid. The problem is that for 6*6 there were a lot of plausible solutions so  it would take absurd amount of time to get the results by hand.

The real problem is that I need to create a proof to why for example a 4*4 grids lowest number of colored cells is 7 and that is the thing I have been struggling with. I also need to understand in what manner should I color the cells to get the results I need so that I can get the results on my own as n gets larger.

Maybe some of you could recommend some scientific papers that adress this kind of problem or help me figure out in what way should I color the cells.

Any help would be much appreciated. Tnx :)

Comment: I think this question is interesting, but I think you will get better responses if you improve the presentation. As it stands I read at least three questions: how to make larger solutions, how to determine the minimum number of cells possible, and references on the general problem. It would help if you could be very explicit and clear what you are looking for. Furthermore, the statement "as far as I have seen 0 doesn't satisfy the requirements" is very vague. The statement "there is only one solution for a 2*2 grid" does not make sense to me, it seems that there should be at least 10.

Comment: And if you're just looking for large solutions, why not paint stripes like your second 4x4 grid? It seems that that always works.

Comment: A chequerboard pattern always works, but how much better can you do?

Comment: Yes I can get one solution from painting stripes or doing a chequerboard pattern but I need to find all of the possible number of colored cells that satisfy the requirements @MarkBennet

Comment: So tell me if i understand correctly: in every 2*2 square there should be 1 or 2  coloured grid squares and if you color any of the remaining ones the result would not be good?

Comment: For an even-sided grid, split it into two by two blocks. Each of these blocks can have at most two coloured squares, so the maximum is half the squares are coloured. For odd sided (2n+1) the stripe pattern allows $n$ or $n+1$ stripes.  You can get as few as $12$ in a six by six block by colouring the second and fifth rows. Any horizontal row must have blank cells above and below and there can be gaps of two rows between filled rows (so blank two by two squares can exist if these arrangements are valid)

Comment: Yes. The important part is that if you color any of the empty squares there HAS to be a 2*2 square that has 3 colored cells. So then the solution would be the original grid without any of the 2*2 squares having 3 cells colored. Checking if coloring any of the empty cells to see if there is a 2*2 square with 3 cells colored is just a method to check if your solution is right ;) @LazarIonutRadu

Comment: Also I have come up with a formula for maximum values of colored cells. If n is an even number the formula is (n*n)/2 because hal of the cells are colored. If n is odd the formula for maximum value of colored cells is (n*n)/2 + n/2 @MarkBennet

Comment: It seems to me that every square is made of a combination of stripes and chequerboard patters. If we denote every 2*2 squares a value C ( chequerboard ), S ( stripes ) or P ( single point, as in a 4*4 example ) we can see that between any 2 2*2 squares that share 2 blocks there are a set of rules regarding their values, by example P and C can not be adiacent

Comment: However SC does not denote a unique 2*3 rectangle. Maybe a further categorization of C into C1 and C2 and S into S1 and S2 ( horizontal and vertical stripes ) would solve this problem

Comment: I think it is more important to look at the empty spaces to see if the requirement is met. Still struggling to find the rule of coloring these cells :DD @LazarIonutRadu

Comment: @Emils This problem is truly hard, may I ask where did you get it from?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is similar to Martin Gardner's no-three-in-a-line problem, which is discussed in OEIS entry [A219760](https://oeis.org/A219760).

A similar integer linear programming formulation yields the following min and max values for the number of colored cells in your problem if you require 1 or 2 colored cells in each 2x2 square:

```
 n min max
 2   2   2 
 3   3   6 
 4   7   8 
 5   9  15 
 6  13  18 
 7  17  28 
 8  22  32 
 9  28  45 
10  35  50 
11  41  66
```

**Edit**: here are the min and max values for the number of colored cells in your problem if you require 0, 1, or 2 colored cells in each 2x2 square:

```
 n min max
 2   2   2
 3   3   6
 4   7   8
 5   9  15
 6  12  18
 7  17  28
 8  22  32
 9  27  45
10  34  50
11  41  66
```

I used an integer linear programming formulation that is identical to the one in the linked OEIS entry if you change SQUARES[k] to $\text{CELLS}_k$, the set of cells that appear in 2x2 square $k$ and LINES[i,j] to $\text{SQUARES}_{i,j}$, the set of 2x2 squares that contain cell $(i,j)$.  Explicitly, the problem is to minimize or maximize $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ subject to:
\begin{align}
2 y_k \le \sum_{(i,j) \in \text{CELLS}_k} x_{i,j} &\le 2 &&\text{for all 2x2 squares $k$} \\
x_{i,j} + \sum_{k \in \text{SQUARES}_{i,j}} y_k &\ge 1 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \\
x_{i,j} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \\
y_k &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for all $k$}
\end{align}

**Edit**: By request, here is the SAS code I used for the LP relaxation of the minimization problem:

```
proc optmodel printlevel=0;
   num n;
   set ROWS = 1..n;
   set COLS = ROWS;
   set CELLS = ROWS cross COLS;
   set SQUARES = {i in ROWS diff {n}, j in COLS diff {n}};
   set CELLS_square {<i,j> in SQUARES} = i..i+1 cross j..j+1;

   var X {CELLS} binary;
   min MinNumColored = sum {<i,j> in CELLS} X[i,j];

   /* if X[i,j] = 0, then some square containing <i,j> has exactly 2 colored */
   var Y {SQUARES} binary;
   con TwoByTwoGE {<i,j> in SQUARES}:
      sum {<ii,jj> in CELLS_square[i,j]} X[ii,jj] >= 2 * Y[i,j];
   con TwoByTwoLE {<i,j> in SQUARES}:
      sum {<ii,jj> in CELLS_square[i,j]} X[ii,jj] <= 2;
   con YCon {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      X[i,j] + sum {<ii,jj> in SQUARES: <i,j> in CELLS_square[ii,jj]} Y[ii,jj] >= 1;

   set NSET = 2..11;
   num opt {NSET};
   do n = NSET;
      solve with lp relaxint;
      print X;
      opt[n] = _OBJ_;
   end;
   print opt;
quit;
```

Comment: These are almost the results that I have got. There is a case where where n=6 min can be 12 too but this is definetely going in the right direction. Do you have the source code from which you got these results maybe? @RobPratt

Comment: Also if I understand correctly this linear programming formulation has a similar idea to that of no-three-in-a-line problem so I should be looking more into that to understand and develop solution to my own problem? @RobPratt

Comment: Please show me your $n=6$ solution with 12 colored cells.

Comment: So a 2x2 square with colored cells is acceptable?  Based on your original description, I had imposed 1 or 2 colored cells.

Comment: Yeah that's my fault. I forgot that this case existed. As long as if an empty cell is colored there should be a 2*2 square with 3 colored cells so yes it is acceptable. @RobPratt

Comment: I would conjecture from these that the maximum in every case results from completely coloring every other row. Would it be possible to prove this?

Comment: In fact, the linear programming relaxation attains this upper bound $n \lceil n/2 \rceil$, even if you omit the $y$ variables and enforce only the $\le 2$ constraints, so you should be able to derive a proof via LP duality.

Comment: Actually, for maximization, the even $n$ case is clear by partitioning the grid into (disjoint) 2x2 squares.

Comment: The thing that I need to do now would be to create a mathematical proof for the results. Do you think it could be possible to do this using the linear programming formulation and LP duality?(I haven't looked into linear programming or LP duality so I am not sure what I can do with them) @RobPratt

Comment: I used the LP solver in [SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/or/).

Comment: To respect integrality, just omit the *with lp relaxint* option from the *solve* statement.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember how long it took, but I do know that most of the time was spent proving optimality (increasing the lower bound after an optimal solution was found).

Comment: What version of SAS Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using SAS University Edition@RobPratt

Comment: Depending on your configuration, you might be able to increase the timeout via More application options->Preferences->Session time-out->Time-out interval

Comment: So is SAS studio speed depending on my internet speed or is this problem just too big for SAS or any other optimiser to handle more quickly than it is doing right now?@RobPratt

Comment: The bottleneck here is the solver speed, and any solver will have difficulty for sufficiently large $n$.  Finding additional constraints that tighten the formulation could significantly speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of a proof that a $4\times 4$ square must have at least seven coloured squares. You should be able to fill in the gaps.

Let's call the $1\times 1$ squares cells, and divide the $4\times 4$ square into four disjoint $2\times 2$ blocks. Number columns $1$ to $4$ left to right, and rows $1$ to $4$ from top to bottom.

Each block can contain at most two coloured cells. If it contains no coloured cells then the corner cell of the block [the one at position $1,1$ or $1,4$ or $4,1$ or $4,4$] can be coloured contrary to the restriction. If the block contains just one coloured cell, and this is not a corner cell, then the corner cell can likewise be coloured.

Suppose the top left block contains just one coloured cell, it must be the corner cell $1,1$. Then for $2,1$ to leave a $2\times 2$ square with three coloured squares, $3,1$ and $3,2$ must be coloured, and similarly $1,3$ and $2,3$. That deals with three of the four blocks.

If the bottom right block contains two coloured cells we are up to $7$ and if just one it must be $4,4$ which forces $2,4$ and $4,2$ in violation of the rules (and taking the total to $8$ anyway).

So the minimum number for $4\times 4$ is seven.

Comment: @Emils I am suggesting quartering the square and looking just at the quarters to start with. The other squares are relevant, but the thing has to work for the quarters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good start on a proof that $n \lceil n/2 \rceil$ is optimal for the linear programming relaxation of the maximization problem, even without the $y$ variables and associated constraints.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j}$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j) \in \text{CELLS}_k} x_{i,j} &\le 2 &&\text{for all $k$, with dual variable $\pi_k \ge 0$}\\
-x_{i,j} &\le 0 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$, with dual variable $\alpha_{i,j} \ge 0$} \\
x_{i,j} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$, with dual variable $\beta_{i,j} \ge 0$}
\end{align}
For even $n$, an optimal primal solution is $x_{i,j}=1/2$ for all $(i,j)$, with objective value $n^2/2$.  An optimal dual solution is $\pi_k = 1/2$ for each 2x2 square $k$ whose top-left corner has odd coordinates, $\pi_k=0$ otherwise, and  $\alpha_{i,j}=\beta_{i,j}=0$ for all $(i,j)$.  Multiplying both sides of the constraints by these dual multipliers and adding up both sides yields $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j} \le n^2/2$, so this primal-dual pair provides a certificate of optimality.

For odd $n$, an optimal primal solution is
$$x_{i,j} = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $i$ and $j$ are both odd}, \\
0 & \text{if $i$ and $j$ are both even}, \\
1/2 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
with objective value $n \lceil n/2 \rceil$.  An optimal dual solution is $\alpha_{i,j}=1/\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ if $i$ and $j$ are both even, $\beta_{i,j}=1/\lceil n/2 \rceil$ if $i$ and $j$ are both odd, and a more complicated formula for $\pi_k$.  For $n=3$, take $\pi_k = 1/2$ for all $k$. For $n=5$, take
$$\pi_k=
\begin{cases}
2/3 &\text{if the top-left corner of square $k$ has coordinates in $\{1,4\}$},\\
1/6 &\text{if the top-left corner of square $k$ has coordinates in $\{2,3\}$},\\
1/3 &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Again, these dual multipliers yield $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j} \le n \lceil n/2 \rceil$, so this primal-dual pair provides a certificate of optimality.

It remains to describe $\pi_k$ for larger odd $n$, but please check your understanding so far.  In particular, it is a good exercise to verify that the dual solutions provided for $n=3$ and $n=5$ do in fact show that $\sum_{i,j} x_{i,j} \le n \lceil n/2 \rceil$.

Comment: And do I use the same reasoning for minimisation? @RobPratt

Comment: Yes, you can also solve the linear programming relaxation for the minimization problem, but the resulting lower bound is weak.  2: 1.3333,
3: 2.3333,
4: 4,
5: 5.1429,
6: 7.0413,
7: 8.9375,
8: 11.2614,
9: 13.6761,
10: 16.3914,
11: 19.3081

Comment: So how did you get the minimisation results that you posted earlier when the lower bound is not the right results that you achieved? @RobPratt

Comment: The earlier minimization results were from enforcing integrality (using an integer linear programming solver).  The lower bounds in today's comment are from relaxing integrality (using a linear programming solver).  For the maximization version of your problem, these values happen to agree with each other, but for the minimization version they do not.

Comment: So it could be possible to get a formula that works for minimal solutions just like the previous formula about maximum values for n right? @RobPratt

Comment: For the minimization problem, you can probably get a formula for the LP lower bound, but I suspect that the optimal integer objective value does not have a simple formula.